# How to to share context between Safari and Native App?

Tags: ios, html, native

I have a need to **set some context via Safari** (a context token), and then **read that context from a native iOS app**. What are the best practices for doing this?

A couple thoughts so far:

1. Set the context in an HTML 5 database, but I'm not sure this will work because the database might be only accessible from Safari. **Would using a WebUIView in the native app allow me to access the same HTML5 database / local storage as Safari**?
2. Set the context in device storage, but I'm not sure this will work because I don't know if Safari can actually write to device storage.

Comment: Are you going to be launching the app from the browser? Or is the app just going to be opened later by the user?

Comment: @JesseRusak - It's a little complicated, but whats happening is the user is emailed a URL with a unique "context token" in it. They open that in Safari. That then redirects them to the Apple App Store to download the application. Once the application is downloaded we need to know that original "context token". Today we are just sending the user an SMS with a custom URL that we handle in the app, and parse the context token out of that, but that is not a desirable behavior. We are looking for a better way to pass this context, and get rid of the SMS message.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would suggest one of these two options:

- Let the web server keep track on the user both in the app and on the website, for example by creating a user account.

or

- Pass the context token to the app immediately via an URL-scheme by registering your app as a protocol handler, see more info [here](http://mobileorchard.com/apple-approved-iphone-inter-process-communication/)

  Suggested way:

  1. Send e-mail with link and context token, when user clicks link, save context token in cookie in safari, then redirect to appstore for app download.
  2. When the user downloaded the app and opens it, present a button for the user, when the user clicks it, open a web page in safari.
  3. Safari loads the cookie with the context token, and then triggers another link using a URL-scheme like yourAppName://contextToken=12345678. The link opens your app which reads the context token from the URL.

There is no best practice for directly sharing data between safari and a native app directly and that it is simply not intended that you should do that. All cookies and storages are sandboxed for each app and safari has its own sandbox.

Letting your server doing the job via user accounts is the best and clean way i.m.o. That is why you have user accounts. If you didn't try out the protocol handler for reading specific URLs, that could also be made handy I think.

Comment: Cool idea. I wonder if the user would have a poor user experience by bouncing back between Safari and the native app when they first opened it?

Comment: Of course, it wouldn't be a top user experience and seem a bit confusing, but I can't think of a better way if you really want to avoid a registration process for the user. However since you already send some kind of token to a user via e-mail, in a sense that means that you do have a registration process anyway and you might aswell go all the way through with it. Look at apps like WhatsApp or games like WordFeud - both have quick registration processes that don't make them any less popular.

Comment: TechCrunch has reported that this method is now causing apps to be rejected by Apple. http://techcrunch.com/2013/02/25/apple-rejecting-apps-using-cookie-tracking-methods-signaling-push-to-its-own-ad-identifier-technology-is-now-underway/

Comment: Yes, to prevent misusage of Ads it seems. The intention here is not about advertisement, but a part of the registration process. If this is clear to Apple, it may still be allowed. Or maybe not - if Apple wants to discourage all "safari flip-flopping", ad or not. However there is no way to be sure, except trying =)

Comment: You're also introducing a security vulnerability by assuming that the app claiming to be, `yourAppName://contextToken=12345678` is actually your app and not a malicious actor trying to steal your session... universal link is a good workaround.

Answer (score 1):

Could you have the app hit a URL on first launch hosted by server which is redirecting the user in safari, and compare IP addresses, time, iOS version, etc to get at least an approximate match? If an approximate match is insufficient, you could, when you see an approximate match, have your app open safari to confirm their identify via cookie.

Comment: I don't get the cookie part... ? Safari can't access cookies from an app, they are sandboxed...

Comment: You could confirm their identity by checking a cookie (in Safari) which was set when the user first visits the site. This would let you figure out which context they should have, and let you redirect them to the app (via URL scheme) with the correct context.

Comment: Also, doesn't iOS 6 have something like this? They announced some way to launch an app (or the app store) from a web site and pass along context info, didn't they?

Comment: @JesseRusak you have a ref?

Comment: @LukeMcneice Yes, they are called [Smart App Banners](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariWebContent/PromotingAppswithAppBanners/PromotingAppswithAppBanners.html)

Comment: @JesseRusak: This only passes context info to an app that is already installed. You can already do this with custom URIs.

Comment: @user102008 The main reason I think smart app banners are better is that they offer to install it if you don't have the app; I don't know any way to detect if the user has an app installed in a web view without showing them an ugly error.

Answer (score -1):

It’s easy to send messages between  a UIWebView and your native up using [WebViewJavascriptBridge](https://github.com/marcuswestin/WebViewJavascriptBridge).

In your case, though, the accepted answer’s suggestion of using a custom URL scheme (directly from email to app, post-install) makes the most sense.