# iOS app pass specific id when app install from link

Tags: ios, iphone, ios7, ios6, mobile-safari

Project Detail :-

I am developing simple application in iOS,When app start there is one specific id or you can  say password for specific user for login.

E.G.
I am installing app from link and link contain 12345 password,so when app installed from link and open app first time that password use as login. when other link contain abcde as password and install from link and open app first time that abcde password used without entering that from user.

Is there any way to pass specific id in url when app install first time from link.
[As Per Apple Documentation about Promoting Apps with Smart App Banners](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariWebContent/PromotingAppswithAppBanners/PromotingAppswithAppBanners.html)

Is there any possibility to pass custom/specific parameter when user install from Smart App Banner and get that custom/specific parameter when app launch first time?.

I have read in forum and didn't get full information that it is possible or not?.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11763494/how-to-to-share-context-between-safari-and-native-app please Refer this Url is will helping something you..

Answer (score 2):

Not both install and open with information at the same time.

You have on link to go to the app store to get the app. You have another completely separate link to open the app *once it is installed* and pass it some information. From a user point of view these are 2 distinct tasks.

In the page you link to, `app-id=myAppStoreID` supports getting the app from the store and `app-argument=myURL` supports opening the existing app with supplied information. But, the user would click the banner once to go to the store and get the app, then return to Safari and click the banner again to open the app.